# Reading values from TI BLE CC2540 on android fails with status = 10

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a device with CC2540 chip that I try to connect and read / write data from Android.

The device is discovered, I am able to connect, but when I try to send read command I get status = 10 at:

```
public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status)
```

I used "BLE sensor tag" source code and changed UUIDs according to mine - I get the same result

I used "BLE device monitor" app from Google Play - I get the same result (screen shot attached)

My questions are:

1. What does "status = 10" stands for?
2. Where does it comes from? The chip? Android?
3. How can debug it?

I have an iPhone device and it works great...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does "status = 10" stands for?

It can be anything really, since you can't access to BLE Device Monitor's source. You can find generic GATT profile status codes [here(BluetoothGatt)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html)

Do you see the same error code when you run TI's "BleSensorTag" source example?

> Where does it comes from? The chip? Android?
>   How can debug it?

That's what Android's [BluetoothGattCallback()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html) function interprets from the chip accessing it through [BluetoothAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html).

I recommend focusing on "BleSensorTag" source code;
For the status code find

```
private BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallbacks = new BluetoothGattCallback()
```

in "BluetoothLeService.java" about line #82. That's where you get the status code and those overridden callbacks then registered to [BluetoothDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html) object's [connectGatt()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#connectGatt%28android.content.Context,%20boolean,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback%29) method.

```
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallbacks)
```

I would also make sure that my BLE packets are in the correct form using TI's [sniffer](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/BLE_sniffer_guide) if possible. If not you may as well debug what's coming out of [BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback.html)

Again in the "BleSensorTag" find `public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord)` method in MainActivity.java. And change;

```
public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Filter devices
```

to:

```
public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {

      final byte[] scanRecordStream = scanRecord;

      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Filter devices

            Log.i(TAG, "scanRecord:" + Conversion.BytetohexString(scanRecordStream, scanRecordStream.length));
```

rest is the same and you should see your byte stream in the logcat.

[edit]
Here is the **LE Generic Packet Structure** according to Core Bluetooth Spec V4.0

[image]

The following is an example BLE packet byte structure, I added it as an example in case you might want to compare your packet's length when you log it on the console and have something to use as a reference.

A BLE advertising packet could be expected to have the generic form:

```
02 01 06 1A FF 4C 00 02 15: iBeacon prefix (fixed)
B9 40 7F 30 F5 F8 46 6E AF F9 25 55 6B 57 FE 6D: proximity UUID (here: Estimote’s fixed UUID)
00 49: major
00 0A: minor
C5: 2’s complement of measured TX power
```

Happy debugging.

Comment: It's not really clear why you are appending an iBeacon-format advertising packet to your post; iBeacon has **nothing** to do with the ordinary BLE service characteristics this question seeks to read.

Comment: Actually you are right. I added it in order provide a reference when he logs his own byte stream in the console, as in "your byte stream will look something like this". For in depth detail please refer to Bluetooth Core V4.0 spec document or later.